# Invalid Text Representation when writing Pandas Table into Database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a simple dataframe gg:

```
   id commodity prediction_date  price_on_prediction_date  \
0   2  cc_wheat      2023-04-02                     265.0   

   predicted_time_range  predicted_price predicted_date  occurred_price  \
0                    28       219.015029     2023-04-30          237.25   

  date_of_occured_price trend_prediction trend_real result feature_id  
0            2023-04-30                ⬇          ⬇    NaN  554701139
```

The goal is to write it into a Database with a custom class that relays on psycogy2. This is the code:

```
pig.fast_write(gg, 'hist_prog_cc_wheat_9', engine=new_pred, schema='prediction', mode='append')
```

Simple explanation:

```
pig.fast_write(dataframe, tablename in database, engine, editmode)
```

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "2023-04-02"
CONTEXT:  COPY hist_prog_cc_wheat_9, line 1, column prediction_date: "2023-04-02"
```

The datatypes for `prediction_date` and the same column in the database are the same. The database runs on postgresql.
How can I fix this?

Comment: @not_speshal thank you. This worked, my thoughts were way to difficult

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that the data type for the column in the database is `double precision`. `"2023-04-02"` is a string.